# BigQuery Fails Silently

Tags: google-bigquery

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

dataset_ref = client.dataset('bigquery_error')
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
dataset.location = 'US'
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset)

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('age', 'INTEGER'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('other', 'INTEGER'),
]

dataset_ref = client.dataset('bigquery_error')
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('user_table')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # API request

rows = [
    ('111', 9, 9),
    (123, 123, 123),
]
# upload postgres data
table_ref = client.dataset('bigquery_error').table('user_table')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows)
print(errors)
assert errors == []
```

This will not write to the table, but doesn't raise any errors.  I query the database immediately after in the UI to see if the write succeeded and it shows 0 rows.  Shouldn't there be an error if a write isn't completing successfully?

NOTE:  From reading a git issue, an engineer states:

`Yeah, this is a known backend issue. Basically, it can take 2 minutes for the streaming buffer's cache of where tables are located to update, so the writes after a delete and recreate can end up going to the deleted table's files in that 2 minute window.`

Comment: "This will not write" How do you know?

Comment: I query the database afterwards to see if the rows inserted

Comment: I believe this is related to this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3822

The streaming api will fail if you write to a table/dataset that was recently deleted and recreated.